SQL Server transposing rows to columns
I need to transpose rows to columns to display data in different dimensions or meet table format requirements using SQL server.
Starting from this query and this return
SELECT 
  _p,
  _t,
  _x,
 COUNT (*) _q 
FROM
    [dbo].[subset_data] 
WHERE
    CONVERT ( VARCHAR ( 10 ), data, 120 ) = CONVERT ( VARCHAR ( 10 ), GETDATE( ), 120 ) 
    GROUP BY
    _p,
    _t,
    _x;


+--------+--------------+----------+--------+
| _p     | _t           |   _x     |   _q   |
+--------+--------------+----------+--------+
| 001    | 06:00-12:00  |   15     |    1   |
| 001    | 12:00-18:00  |   15     |    1   |
| 008    | 06:00-12:00  |    5     |    2   |
| 009    | 12:00-18:00  |    6     |    1   |
| 010    | 06:00-12:00  |   12     |    1   |
+--------+--------------+----------+--------+

I have to get this return
+--------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| _p     | 00:00-06:00  | 06:00-12:00 | 12:00-18:00 | 18:00-23:59 |    _x      |
+--------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| 001    |      0       |      1      |      1      |      0      |    15      |
| 008    |      0       |      2      |      0      |      0      |     5      |
| 009    |      0       |      0      |      1      |      0      |     6      |
| 010    |      0       |      1      |      0      |      0      |    12      |
+--------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------+

Where the row values of column _t are to be converted to columns and for each value of the _p column I have to retrieve the value of the row from _q column.
Can you help me?
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE subset_data (
   data DATETIME,
  _p VARCHAR(100),
  _t VARCHAR(100),
  _x VARCHAR(100),
);

INSERT INTO subset_data(data, _p, _t, _x) VALUES (GETDATE(), '001', '06:00-12:00', '15');
INSERT INTO subset_data(data, _p, _t, _x) VALUES (GETDATE(), '001', '12:00-18:00', '15' );
INSERT INTO subset_data(data, _p, _t, _x) VALUES (GETDATE(), '008', '06:00-12:00', '5' );
INSERT INTO subset_data(data, _p, _t, _x) VALUES (GETDATE(), '008', '06:00-12:00', '5' );
INSERT INTO subset_data(data, _p, _t, _x) VALUES (GETDATE(), '009', '12:00-18:00', '6');
INSERT INTO subset_data(data, _p, _t, _x) VALUES (GETDATE(), '010', '06:00-12:00', '12');

SQLFiddle
My attempt to use PIVOT is as follows:
select  
  _p, _t, _x
from
(
  select _p
  from [dbo].[subset_data] 
) d
pivot
(
  _p
  for _p in (_p, _t, _x)
) piv;

Error
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server IT000001861251, Procedure , Line 0
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.
> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'. (156)


Does this answer your question? SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?

Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question? Explain what the problem you are having solving the problem. What have you tried? Why isn't it working? What about the 100's (if not 1,000's) of questions about pivoting and unpivoting didn't you understand?

Doesn't look like it ever needs to be dynamic, @Brad . It's set to specific 6 hour windows.

Does this answer your question? Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server

@ThomA I have tried your suggestion, but I have error and I don't think it's right for me

And that attempt is..? That error is..? We can't see your screen, @Hamamelis , so we can't see why it's not working, but pivoting/conditional aggregation does appear to be what you are after.

@ThomA Please, see EDIT in the question

You don't define an aggregate in your PIVOT, @Hamamelis . <Aggregate Expression> FOR ... And that attempt looks nothing like the suggestions. Have another check. None of the rows in the column _p have the value '_p', '_t', or '_x'. And you have a typographical error: _x,); there's a trailing comma.

This is a simple conditional aggregation, of which there are many answers already. Check out https://dbfiddle.uk/UaK0QNGi for example

Does this answer your question? Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server

FWIW glad my database columns do not have names like that...

The attempt you've made has a lot of flaws:

Your derived table d only exposes the column _p, so _t, and _x aren't accessible.
Your PIVOT lacks an aggregate function.
You are trying to check the value of _p, but it _t you want to check
You are checking if the column (_p) has the value '_p', '_t', or '_x' but those values never appear in that column, nor the column you actually want to pivot on (_t).
You have (had) a trailing comma in your IN clause.

The suggested duplicate, Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server, shows you how to properly use PIVOT, which is in the format:
SELECT <Columns List from Pivoted derived table>
FROM (SELECT <Columns List>
      FROM <Table Name> --Your Table) <Alias>
PIVOT (<Aggregate Expression>
       FOR <Column to PIVOT on> IN (<Delimited list of Values to PIVOT on>)) <Pivot Alias>;

For your data, this results in the following:
SELECT _p,
       [00:00-06:00],
       [06:00-12:00],
       [12:00-18:00],
       [18:00-23:59],
       _x
FROM (SELECT _p,
             _t,
             _x
        FROM [dbo].[subset_data]) d
PIVOT (COUNT(_t)
       FOR _t IN ([00:00-06:00],[06:00-12:00],[12:00-18:00],[18:00-23:59])) piv
ORDER BY _p;

Personally, as always, however, I suggest conditional aggregation; the syntax is less "clunky", it's less restrictive, and it's (more) transferable to other dialects:
SELECT _p,
       COUNT(CASE _t WHEN '00:00-06:00' THEN 1 END) AS [00:00-06:00],
       COUNT(CASE _t WHEN '06:00-12:00' THEN 1 END) AS [06:00-12:00],
       COUNT(CASE _t WHEN '12:00-18:00' THEN 1 END) AS [12:00-18:00],
       COUNT(CASE _t WHEN '18:00-23:59' THEN 1 END) AS [18:00-23:59],
       _x
FROM dbo.subset_data sd
GROUP BY _p,
         _x
ORDER BY _p;

